# Python socket recv data parsing

Tags: python, c++, sockets

I am trying to send image data from c++ to python using socket. The format of data sent from c++ is [data1,data2...] (includes ",")

When I print data received in python, it looks like this.

Print in python

[image]

I would like to parse and rearrange it to image array. How should I approach?

```
HOST, PORT = "localhost", 50007

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((HOST, PORT))
for x in range(0, 1):
    print("Step 1")
    s.send(b'Hello')
    print("Step 2")
    data = s.recv(1000000)
    print(data)
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: What format is the image data? What are you planning to do with it? How you describe the format here is also very vague.

Comment: You could show the code of your application in c++